# Task status tracking

Tags: communication, tracking, task-management

Independent from project type (agile/non-agile) and independent from the depth and size of projects and tasks,  I need to keep tracking multiple tasks of multiple projects.
Currently I use a status-list of multiple projects. So each item is a project. Under each project-item I put a task. This is only for status-tracking. Not for organisation, planning etc. Here is an example:

```
Level 1:  
- Building a house  
- Organize next vacation  

Level 2:  
- Building a house  
-- Plan the costs  

Level 3:
- Building a house  
-- Plan the costs  
--- Status 24.09.2015; 
Message: Could not estimate my available money  
Status: Critical  
Due Date: 08.12.2015  {code}
```

Now the problem with that is, when people are using this kind of status report, it easily leads to losing the focus on the due-date. So on the next entry it might be the same task ("plan the cost") with a new due date. Because they are allowed to change the due date. Well that is OK, but when changing the due date I want to ensure people are aware that they delay the task.

This is my request:
What process do you use/recommend to make people aware that they delay the task.

Notice: I would like to avoid e-mail-communication. I would be glad to see suggestions like "new/approved" status-management methods.

Edit: As suggested by an answer (below), in this case it is not an option to do the reporting in the work-tools or pm tools (like jira, ms project etc.). The reporting needs to be written/stored at the same place for all project-types.

Comment: I'm not even sure that the organizational structure of your breakdown makes sense. Why not just use an indented outline that you treat as a living document with revision tracking?

Comment: @CodeGnome That's what I do, but based on each task. I don't use revision tracking, but that's not the focus in my request. I would like to focus on "How to make people aware of delayed tasks?". 
Any tools to recommend?

Comment: Tool recommendations are out of scope for PM.SE.  In my opinion, this question isn't sufficiently clear to answer.  While there is a lot of detail about *how*, I don't understand the *what* - what is the goal and what are the real constraints. Perhaps it is just me.

Answer (score 1):

### Minimize paperwork

> Because they are allowed to change the due date. Well that is OK, but
>   when changing the due date I want to ensure people are aware that they
>   delay the task... What tool/process do you use/recommend to make
>   people aware that they delay the task.

The notion of a due date and a change in the due date are built into most project management tools. All you have to do is to establish a baseline initially. Once you do that, the tool will show assigned resource, scheduled and actual delay. [In this link you can see, for example, how to do that in MS Project.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Review-the-progress-of-your-schedule-0d24c633-f572-44b9-8fdb-56e1f5095237)

> Independent from project type (agile/non-agile) and independent from
>   the depth and size of projects and tasks, I need to keep tracking
>   multiple tasks of multiple projects.

However, you cannot do that with agile projects. Agile projects do not have the notion of a timeline committed in advance for a task nor the notion of an assigned resource. If they are, they wouldn't be agile. These are characteristics of predictive processes. Agile is an adaptive process. For example, in Scrum, stories remain in the backlog and can be moved up or down (re-prioritized) until they are scheduled into a sprint.

Also, what you are attempting to do appears to be adding avoidable paperwork burden on the resources. You presumably have other tools to track your agile projects and non-agile projects. I strongly recommend against making resources fill out and watch additional tools and processes.

Comment: The extra report is necessary because there are different project types, project methods and tools that people use in my case. And thus the report  needs to be similiar for efficiency in status meetings. Thats a requirement. So your answer is valid, for project management that allows status reports in the work-tools. But this (my) request is asking for a tool/process to explicit status-reporting independently from the project type.